# What is this odd discoloration on laptop screen?

Tags: laptop, display

In the last year or two I have noticed some odd lines on my Dell XPS. Even when the surface of the screen (bonded gorilla glass) is completely cleaned, and unscratched, it looks like lines of pixels wore out or got something rubbed off of them.

At sideways angles the lines aren't really visible. The screen is <1cm thick metal and I wonder if pressing on screen side from outside may have caused it to wear/rub? Pictures make a screen look odd, but you can see it here next to cursor on a white screen:

[image: line in screen]

[image: line in screen]

Answer (score 0):

The pictures aren't very clear, but from what I can see the pixels in the pointer are quite defined (you can see the edges) while the lines are not, which makes me think they are indeed scratches. If you drag your finger over them, do you feel any change in texture? Gorilla Glass is good, but on a screen around or over two years old, scratches are far from impossible, and judging by the pictures it doesn't look like dead pixels.

Comment: No, the glass is mirror smooth and after cleaning doesn't even have that line of rubbed-in dirt that gets caked in screens like that of the Macbook.